# In QT Trying to receive data from specific IP address using UDP

Tags: qt, udp

I am trying to receive data from specific IP address (like 166.0.0.245) using UDP protocol in QT. I am having multiple connections in my network which are udp.

But the problem is i am receiving from any ip address rather than specific IP address.

Below i am attaching my code where i am setting the ip address of my receiver i.e 166.0.0.34 and my senders IP address is 166.0.0.245 -> where do i specifically set this ip address so that i can receive only that ip address and discard rest of the ip address in my network.
Plz can somebody suggest me where do i specifically set my ip address at the receivers side which accepts only one sender with specific ip address and port.

Thanks in advance

```
NetBroadcasterDlg::NetBroadcasterDlg(QWidget *parent) :  //Main Function
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::NetBroadcasterDlg)
{
    // ethernet initialisation and binding  wini
    udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    udpSocket_send = new QUdpSocket(this);

    udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress("166.0.0.34"), 1100, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
    connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));
...
}

void NetBroadcasterDlg::processPendingDatagrams()
{
    // Read data from ethernet
    while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
        datagram.resize(int(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize()));

        udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size()); 

// Sending data to the Target

        udpSocket_send->writeDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                                 QHostAddress("166.168.1.20"), 2500);   //target address and port
...
}
```

Comment: Not sure I've understood the question, but I think you should filter the address on receive. Like `udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(), &address);` then `if (address != QHostAddress("166.0.0.245")) return;`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, what i meant was i need to receive the data from only one ip address, how do i set @ receivers end  take data from only this ip address and rest all neglect it.

Comment: The standard way to achieve this with BSD sockets would be to call [connect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) on the UDP socket.  As Qt doesn't allow access to the underlying socket descriptor (as far as I can see) you might want to try [`udpSocket->connectToHost("166.168.1.20", 2500)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#connectToHost) to see what -- if any -- effect that has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, an open UDP socket is intended to receive anything from any *IP address which is able to open that UDP socket* in your network.
You can either block other IP addresses to connect to this particular interface or

```
QHostAddress fromAddress;
udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),&fromAddress);

if(fromAddress.isEqual(QHostAddress("166.0.0.245")){
// do whatever with your filtered data
}
```

Comment: Thanks i'll try to do that.